# Prove that $\forall x \forall y (A(x,y) \rightarrow \neg A(y,x)) \vdash \forall x \forall y (A(x,y) \rightarrow \neg x = y)$

Tags: predicate-logic

In predicate logic how to prove that:

$$\forall x \forall y (A(x,y) \rightarrow \neg A(y,x)) \vdash \forall x \forall y (A(x,y) \rightarrow \neg x = y)$$

First it should be proven that:

$$x=y \vdash A(x,y)\leftrightarrow A(y,x) $$

(I did prove the second result, but have problems utilizing it).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

1) $∀x∀y(A(x,y)→¬A(y,x))$ --- premise

From it derive : $A(x,x)→¬A(x,x)$ and with TAUT : $(P \to \lnot P) \to \lnot P$ derive : $\lnot A(x,x)$.

2) $A(x,y)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $x=y$ --- assumed [b]

From 2) and 3) derive : $A(x,x)$ --- **contradicition !**

Conclude with : $¬x=y$, discharging [b].

Derive : $A(x,y) \to ¬x=y$, discharging [a].

Comment: @Tony ------- No.

Comment: Is it really legal to add implication to $\forall x \forall y A(x,y)$, should that not produce$ \forall x \forall y (A(x,y)) \rightarrow \neg x = y$